# Create a reminder for incomplete orders in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, orders, order-status

I need to get a list of customers that did not pay yet every 2 days in my mail or anything to keep track on them.

How can I create a notification for orders that are not completed?

Comment: means you are telling if customer added items to cart and if they dont purchase do you want send email ?

Comment: yes, how can i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of free extensions are available [here1](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/abandoned-cart-follow-up-emails-1.html) & [here2](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/abandoned-carts-notifications-1.html)

Also make sure you are sending mails through `mail server` & **cron jobs** are working fine....

```
class Web4pro_Abandonedcart_Block_Email_Order_Items extends Mage_Sales_Block_Items_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('web4pro_abandonedcart/email_order_items.phtml');
    }

    public function getTax($_item)
    {
        if (Mage::helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax()){
            $subtotal = Mage::helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax') . ' : ' .Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item['row_total_incl_tax']);
        } elseif(Mage::helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()) {
            $subtotal = Mage::helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax') . ' : ' . Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item['row_total']) . '<br>'. Mage::helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax') . ' : ' . Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item['row_total_incl_tax']);
        } else {
            $subtotal = Mage::helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax') . ' : ' . Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item['row_total']);
        }
        return $subtotal;
    }

    public function getImage($_item)
    {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->load($_item->getProductId());
        if($product->getImage()=="no_selection"&&$product->getTypeId() == "configurable") {
            $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($product);
            $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
            foreach ($simple_collection as $simple_product) {
                if ($simple_product->getImage() != "no_selection") {
                    $imageUrl = $simple_product->getThumbnailUrl();
                }
            }
        } else {
            $imageUrl = $product->getThumbnailUrl();
        }
        return $imageUrl;
    }

}
```

Comment: how can i check mail server & cron jobs

Comment: firstly you can install any extension & check , if that not works you can check those.....

Comment: join chat @ http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45032/create-a-reminder-for-incomplete-orders-in-admin

Comment: could you pls join